# airflow dag scheduler trigger execution_date

Tags: triggers, scheduler, airflow

---

ENV:  https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

VERSION :1.8.1-1

### Executor  : LocalExecutor

---

DAG SETTING:

```
 start_date: datetime(2018, 1, 8)
 schedule_interval :  daily
```

[image: dag d3 code details picture]

---

---

Current time:[2018-01-11 06:23:00]

[image: d3 dag_run details picture]

**Question**:

1. Why the dag d3's run_id=[scheduled__2018-01-**11**T00:00:00] has not been triggered at the current time[2018-01-11 06:23:00] ?
2. Current time [2018-01-11 06:23:00] , is there any way to schedule trigger the d3's run_id=[scheduled__2018-01-**11**T00:00:00] ,not [scheduled__2018-01-**10**T00:00:00]

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is intentional. The d3 DAG run for `scheduled__2018-01-11T00:00:00` is expected to kickoff sometime starting `2018-01-12T00:00:00Z` when the schedule interval is "complete".

The docs explain this under [Scheduling & Triggers](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers):

> Note that if you run a DAG on a schedule_interval of one day, the run
>   stamped 2016-01-01 will be trigger soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In
>   other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has
>   ended.
>
> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval
>   AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

Comment: is there any setting or conf can make it happen?

Comment: I don’t think so. Any reason you want to? If your job is using the execution date as a parameter you can always subtract a day or use ``prev_execution_date``.